# Как отключить CORS проверку При подключении SignalR клиента (NetCore 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp, signalr, .net

Возникла необходимость подключения к SignalR хабу большого кол-ва клиентов.
На продакшене будет заданна CORS политика отдельно для SignalR хаба, где пропишутся все разрешенные адреса клиентов
в методе `WithOrigins("http://....", http://....")`

Но для тестового сервера хотелось бы не указывать  список  `WithOrigins` а разрешить обращение со всех адресов.

Столкнулся с тем, что необходимо указывать `AllowCredentials()` иначе на клиенте будет ошибка подключения.

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:44138/providerHub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:44111'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."
```

Работающий вариант такой (обязательно указывать WithOrigins адреса):

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:44111")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
);
```

Так не работает (нельзя использовать AllowAnyOrigin вместе с AllowCredentials)

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
);
```

Т.е. на стороне сервера жесткие ограничения по настройки CORS (указывать WithOrigins + AllowCredentials)

```
.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44111")
.AllowCredentials()
```

На примитивном JS клиенте попытался отключить отправку `Credentials` в функции подключения,
указав `connection.withCredentials = false;` Это не помогло.

```
let hubUrl = 'http://localhost:44138/providerHub';
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(hubUrl)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
   
  
//Функция подключения к хабу
async function start()
{
    try {
        if (connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {

            connection.withCredentials = false;  // НЕ СРАБОТАЛО!!!
            await connection.start();
            document.getElementById("stateHub").innerHTML = "CONNECTION IsDone";
            return console.info("CONNECTION IsDone");
        }
        else
        {
            return console.info("Already Connected !!!");
        }
    } catch (err)
    {
        document.getElementById("stateHub").innerHTML = "CONNECTION Errors: " + err.toString();
        return console.error(err.toString());
    }
};
```

Возможно, как-то по другому отключается

Comment: Клиент - это браузер, так? Следовательно проверку CORS можно отключить только в браузере, на сервере это исправить можно только добавлением заголовка в ответы, например `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Другими словами, здесь на стороне C# делать нечего. Ну еще можно сделать так, чтобы второй сервер так же имел текущее доменное имя, тогда не будет кросс-доменного взаимодействия, и CORS утратит силу.

Comment: Да браузер, я думал middleware обработку добавить корректирующий запрос от клиента, но это не совсем верно я считаю

Comment: клиенты будут на React написаны, т.е. если клиент выполняется на браузере и делает запрос, то нужно настраивать браузер?

Comment: Да, [вот что нашел](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/985841) и [вот еще](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711924/disable-cross-domain-web-security-in-firefox)

Comment: Но будьте предельно внимательны и уверены, что вы отключаете CORS только на время разработки. Серфить инет с отключенным CORS не совсем безопасно.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую, понял куда копать